# How to run GDB when executing go project using Heroku local environment

Tags: heroku, go, gdb

I execute my Go program using the following command line:

`godep go install && heroku local -e .env_local`

I wonder how can I use GDB to debug my program when I execute it through Heroku local environment.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try to use gdb? How is it different than attaching to your normal process? (Have you used gdb with go, and are you familiar with gdb's shortcomings when working with go?)

Comment: Finally I ended up by not using the Heroku local environment anymore. My local configuration shouldn't depend on this tool. Then, I switched to `delve` debugger through IntelliJ.